# ckeditor inline save

Tags: save, ckeditor, inline

Building a forum and using Ckeditor for message posting - which works fine using textarea within a form. Now I want user to be able to edit their post so I have ckeditor working inline so user clicks on their post and their message is replaced by ckeditor. That works so far and looks good. But the save button is disabled. I surrounded the whole thing in a form, but of course ckeditor is now a div and not a text area so I guess form will not work. So how do I pass the data on to my PHP?

Another issue is that Ckeditor doesn't seem to work on mobile phone. Can you think of a good simple fallback method for mobiles?

This is the code I am using to render the inline editor;

```
// Uncomment the following code to test the "Timeout Loading Method".
// CKEDITOR.loadFullCoreTimeout = 5;

window.onload = function() {
    // Listen to the double click event.
    if (window.addEventListener)
        document.body.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        document.body.attachEvent('onclick', onClick);

};

function onClick(ev) {
    // Get the element which fired the event. This is not necessarily the
    // element to which the event has been attached.
    var element = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

    // Find out the div that holds this element.
    var name;

    do {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    while (element && (name = element.nodeName.toLowerCase()) &&
            (name != 'div' || element.className.indexOf('edit_post') == -1) && name != 'body');

    if (name == 'div' && element.className.indexOf('edit_post') != -1)
        replaceDiv(element);
}

var editor;

function replaceDiv(div) {
    if (editor)
        editor.destroy();

    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {
        uiColor: '#FFFFFF',
        toolbar: [
            ['Save', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Scayt'],
            '/',
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Blockquote', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'Image', 'Smiley', 'oembed']

        ]
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try overwriting the default save command and using whatever you need to do with the save there.

Something like

```
// Override the normal CKEditor save plugin
CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] =
{
    init : function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'save', 
            {
                modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
                exec : function( editor ) {
                    if(Editor.CheckDirty()) {
                        // Do wahtever you need to do during the save button here
                    } else {
                        alert("NothingToSave);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Save', {label : '@GeneralTerms.Save', command : 'save'} );
    }
}
```